# front end not able to fetch data - security access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, proxy

My react frontend application is returning:
'Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-myapp.com/backoffice/forms' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource'

Therefore i installed http-proxy-middleware in my frontend app as follow:
1-create a setupProxy.js file

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;

module.exports = app => {

    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware(`/backoffice/forms`,
            {
                target: API_ENDPOINT,
                changeOrigin: true,
            })
    )

}
```

Edit my package.json file as follow:

```
{
  "name": "backoffice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "https://api-myapp.com",
  etc etc
}
```

CALL API

```
import axios from "axios";
const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;

async function doGetForms() {

    const headers = {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    let response = await axios.get(API_ENDPOINT + `/backoffice/forms`, headers);
    if (response) return response.data;
}
```

Unfortunately i did not manage to solve the issue. Is this something my backend developer should solve first by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the resource?
I follow this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4B5WgTiKIOY) and assumed it was working with all scenarios...

Comment: install cors, then use it: app.use(cors())

Comment: will it work in my front end as well?